No se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable
Estoy aprendiendo a usar Javascript en Visual Studio Code, en esta ocasión relacionado con el tema de Eventos. Hice el siguiente ejercicio pero me salen los siguientes errores. Quisiera que me colaboraran diciéndome si depronto es el programa que me está fallando o si en verdad estos errores son acertados y en qué estoy fallando. Gracias.
en la linea de !DOCTYPE html  y en la linea de html me sale error en el signo menor que (<). Dice el término (<) no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable, compruebe que dicha ruta sea la correcta o inténtelo de nuevo.
En la linea de "Width 200px" me dice el mismo error pero con el término "width".


En JavaScript, las propiedades de CSS no llevan el signo '-', sino que van en lowerCamelCase, es decir debería escribirse backgroundColor. Además, siempre que hagas una pregunta en este sitio, el codigo debe ir como texto y formateado como codigo con las herramientas del sitio, saludos.

puedes tomar una captura completa del editor de codigo con el archivo abierto

Ese error no suena a HTML, ni nada de desarrollo web. De hecho, eso parece un error de Powershell.
La verdadera pregunta es: ¿cómo estás ejecutando el código?
Supongo que estarás intentando ejecutar el sitio como un comando de terminal.
Por empezar HTML, CSS y Javascript no son archivos ejecutables ni comandos de terminal. La forma de ver el resultado es abriendo el archivo HTML con un navegador.
El único error es que estás asignando mal el estilo CSS. Como mencionaron, los nombres de los estilos se escriben en camelCase en Javascript.
